# Are There Any Applications That Use The FriendFeed API?

Tags: api, friendfeed

Does anyone know any applications that make use of the friendfeed API?

Answer (score 1):

[Ping.fm](http://ping.fm/) posts to FriendFeed.

[FriendDeck](http://www.frienddeck.com/) aggregates from FriendFeed.

Both use remote key authentication and the FriendFeed API.

Answer (score 0):

[FFToGo](http://www.fftogo.com/) is a nice mobile interface for FriendFeed that was built on the FF api.  Its developer was subsequently hired by Friendfeed and still works there.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an auto follow app http://www.ffollo.com built using the new FriendFeed API.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recently released a script that uses the FriendFeed API, it's on [GitHub](https://github.com/adbar/microblog-explorer).